# Boot Camp assistant "Needs more drive space" even though i have enough

Tags: bootcamp, ssd

Trying to get dual boot for my mac and I ran into this issue.

[image: Not enough Storage]

And when I look at my drive status, this is what I see.

[image]

So maybe im doing something wrong but it doesn't seem right that I need "at least 39GB" when I have 46GB available

I do plan on upgrading the storage of this mac soon anyways if I cant get this figured out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootcamp: The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326377/bootcamp-the-startup-disk-does-not-have-enough-space-to-be-partitioned)

Comment: The linked question talks about  clearing time machine backups

Comment: @ankii Is there really enough information in the question to be sure about this being a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

The 46.1 GB may include what Apple calls "purgeable" space. This space can be made available but is not readily so. My suggestion is to clear off more space if possible and try again. I think purgeable space is space occupied by files and folders that haven't been accessed in some time.

Comment: I went and deleted a bunch of files, including stuff like icloud and iphone backups. Storage tab under about this mac reads about 50GB free and boot camp has now decided it needs 40GB available, not 39GB like it originally stated. Still wont install my windows 10 image.