# Why can't I use the windows 10 boot stick I created for my MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I want to install Windows 10 on my MBP (early 2011, 15", high sierra). I followed instructions using BootCamp and got to successfully create a USB stick with Windows 10. At the end of the bootcamp procedure, nothing happens (according to the user guide I expected the Mac to restart.) When I restart, it boots into High Sierra. When I restart holding the Option key, I have a single choice for booting on my ssd, but the usb stick seems undetected.
Thanks for helping!

**edit : output to command `diskutil list`**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.9 GB   disk0s2
 
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD           388.6 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: I would suggest following the steps given in the answer: [How to Use the Command Line Interface (CLI) to Install a BIOS Booting Windows 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391501/when-trying-to-install-windows-10-on-2011-imac-keep-getting-error-0x8007000d-win/391852#391852).

Comment: thanks @DavidAnderson ! I will definitely try and let you know about the results!

Comment: Hello! I finally got the time to try this. Unfortunately, I get stuck at the partition step : I get an error message from the Disk Utility, basically saying I don't have enough space on the SSD to create a partition. Even though there are about 100GB left on the disk. Does it sound right to you ?

Comment: Copy and paste the output from the command `diskutil list` to your question or post the output as a comment.

Comment: Hi there. I found a solution to the partitioning issue here  :  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326377/bootcamp-the-startup-disk-does-not-have-enough-space-to-be-partitioned  . Work in progress...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [you need a MacBook Pro introduced in 2012 or later](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468). I assume it is a firmware compatibility issue, IIRC, UEFI started happening for Macs just around 2012.